# C# xml serializer - serialize derived objects

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I want to serialize the following:

```
[Serializable]
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("Name")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfo))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoB))] 
public class ItemInfo
{
    public string name;

    [XmlArray("Items"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(ItemInfo))]
    public ArrayList arr;

    public ItemInfo parentItemInfo;
}

[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfo))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoB))] 
public class ItemInfoA : ItemInfo
{
...
}

[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfo))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoB))] 
public class ItemInfoB : ItemInfo
{
...
}
```

The class `itemInfo` describes a container which can hold other `itemInfo` objects in the array list, the `parentItemInfo` describes which is the parent container of the item info.

Since `ItemInfoA` and `ItemInfoB` derive from `ItemInfo` they can also be a member of the array list and the `parentItemInfo`, therefore when trying to serialize these objects (which can hold many objects in hierarchy) it fails with exception

```
IvvalidOperationException.`there was an error generating the xml file `
```

My question is:

What attributes do I need to add the `ItemInfo` class so it will be serializable?

Note: the exception is only when the ItemInfo[A]/[B] are initialized with `parentItemInfo` or the arrayList.

Help please!

Thanks!

Comment: Private members aren't serialized with `XmlSerializer`, so `arr` is **never** going to be serialized in this scenario, nor is `parentItemInfo`. I think we need a reproducible example here... also, not important, but `[Serializable]` isn't used by `XmlSerializer`

Comment: Oh, and why use `ArrayList` here? are you on 1.1?

Comment: Also - **none** of the attributes on `ItemInfoA` or `ItemInfoB` are used here...

Comment: Marc Gravell - sorry, see my edited question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the edited question, it looks like you have a loop. Note that `XmlSerializer` is a **tree** serializer, not a **graph** serializer, so it will fail. The usual fix here is to disable upwards traversal:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public ItemInfo parentItemInfo;
```

Note you will have to manually fixup the parents after deserialization, of course.

Re the exception - you need to look at the `InnerException` - it probably tells you exactly this, for example in your `(catch ex)`:

```
while(ex != null) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    ex = ex.InnerException;
}
```

I'm guessing it is actually:

> "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type ItemInfoA."

---

More *generally* on the design, honestly that (public fields, `ArrayList`, settable lists) is bad practice; here's a more typical re-write **that behaves identically**:

```
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("Name")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemInfoB))] 
public class ItemInfo
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly List<ItemInfo> items = new List<ItemInfo>();
    public List<ItemInfo> Items { get { return items; } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemInfo ParentItemInfo { get; set; }
}
public class ItemInfoA : ItemInfo
{
}
public class ItemInfoB : ItemInfo
{
}
```

---

as requested, here's a general (not question-specific) illustration of recursively setting the parents in a hive (for kicks I'm using depth-first on the heap; for bredth-first just swap `Stack<T>` for `Queue<T>`; I try to avoid stack-based recursion in these scenarios):

```
public static void SetParentsRecursive(Item parent)
{
    List<Item> done = new List<Item>();
    Stack<Item> pending = new Stack<Item>();
    pending.Push(parent);
    while(pending.Count > 0)
    {
        parent = pending.Pop();
        foreach(var child in parent.Items)
        {
            if(!done.Contains(child))
            {
                child.Parent = parent;
                done.Add(child);
                pending.Push(child);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I deserialize it as well?

Comment: @gln deserialize it as normal, but then you would have to *either* walk the tree and assign the parents, or write a custom list implementation that does this for you

Comment: @gln - seriously? That is a pretty simple bit of recursion... I'll add the example later (not at a PC right now), but...